# Does using a lower wattage power adapter for a MacBook increase its battery health?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a 16" MBP which comes with a 96W power adapter. With iPhones, I always heard that the faster you charge the battery (i.e., more power you use), the faster the battery degrades. So, instead of using a 96W charger, if I use a 60w charger will it increase the battery health?

Note: I do not use very high-demanding tasks.

Comment: It is true that slower charging would help your battery. However, you would be interfering with the systems expected charging dynamics and are unlikely to achieve any meaningful battery health benefits.

Answer (score 2):

A low-power charger may not have sufficient power to charge your laptop while you are using it. Even though it's plugged in, the charge level may still go down, or stay at the same level. Or it might go up, but only very slowly. If you have peripheral devices connected that use power, the problem may be worse.

Your laptop draws the power that it needs, according to the power management hardware and software, which Apple spends 'some time and money' on optimizing. Any benefits from using a low-power charger are likely to be minimal, and offset by the inconvenience or other unforeseen problems.

There are so many factors that affect a battery's lifespan -- many of which are out of your control -- that my general advice is: just use your laptop as you need it, and don't try to micro-manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

> I do not use very high-demanding tasks.

In this scenario, as rightly pointed out by benwiggy, micro-managing your computer's battery is probably more hassle than it is worth.

However, if you do choose to go this route, using a lower wattage charger is probably not the best solution. If you mostly use your computer plugged in to AC, you could look into limiting the battery charge to 80% using an application like [AlDente](https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente).

Also, you could tweak with the fans on your MacBook to make them ramp up faster than Apple's defaults to keep all components in your computer, including the battery, cooler. There is another third-party app for this: [Macs Fan Control](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/download) (There may be other alternatives too, I use this one). Do ***not*** use this application if you don't know what you are doing - used improperly, it can make your computer unstable or damage it.

Comment: I am a user of macs fan control and have recommended it to some family. How can it make your computer unstable or damage it? I’d like to inform them so that they don’t damage their computers.

Comment: It could happen if one sets the custom control such that the fans don't ramp up till the system gets too hot or sets them to a low constant RPM

Comment: That’s not an issue for me, since I programmed the others’ fan curves to be more aggressive. Just for curiosity’s sake, wouldn’t the components thermal throttle, or in dire cases, shutdown the system before permanent damage occurs?

Comment: The CPU will thermal throttle, sure, but not all components can thermal throttle. For example, the battery's longevity will be reduced due to excessive heat.In fact, I got into fan curve tuning because Apple's default fan control favours silence over cooling (running a 13" MacBook with a 4k display over usb-c pushed the battery to 43 Celsius on idle load).